# How to see what will be updated from repository before issuing "svn update" command?

Tags: svn

I've committed changes in numerous files to a SVN repository from Eclipse.

I then go to website directory on the linux box where I want to update these changes from the repository to the directory there.

I want to say "svn update project100" which will update the directories under "project100" with all my added and changed files, etc.

HOWEVER, I don't want to necessarily update changes that I didn't make.
So I thought I could say "svn status project100" but when I do this I get a totally different list of changes that will be made, none of mine are in the list, which is odd.

Hence to be sure that only my changes are updated to the web directory, I am forced to navigate to every directory where I know there is a change that I made and explicitly update only those files, e.g. "svn update newfile1.php" etc. which is tedious.

Can anyone shed any light on the standard working procedure here, namely how do I get an accurate list of all the changes that are about to be made before I execute the "svn update" command? I thought it was the "status" command.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Try:

```
svn status --show-updates
```

or (the same but shorter):

```
svn status -u
```

Comment: or shorter: svn st -u

Comment: What do the **X**'s mean in the output?

Comment: Also, use: `svn status -q -u` ... Only shows update changes and local changes which relatie to files belonging to the repository.  You don't get  question marks(?) from non-repository files.

Answer (score 59):

Depending on what you want to know between your working copy and the latest svn
server repository, without updating your local working copy, here is what you can
do:

if you want to know what has been changed in svn server repository, run
command:

```
$ svn st -u
```

if you want to know if the same file has been modified both in your local
working copy and in svn server repository, run command:

```
$ svn st -u | grep -E '^M {7}\*'
```

if you want to get list of files changed between a particular revision and
HEAD, run command:

```
$ svn diff -r revisionNumber:HEAD --summarize
```

if you want to get a list of files changed between paticular revisions, run
command:

```
$ svn diff -r revisionNumber:anotherRevisionNumber --summarize
```

if you want to see what will be updated (without actually updating), run
command:

```
$ svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
```

if you want to know what content of a particular file has been changed in svn
server repository compared with your working copy, run command:

```
$ svn diff -r BASE:HEAD ./pathToYour/file
```

if you want to know what contents of all the files have been changed in svn
server repository compared with your working copy, run command:

```
$ svn diff -r BASE:HEAD .
```

Answer (score 45):

You can see what will updated (without actually updating) by issuing:

```
svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
```

More details [here](http://translocator.ws/2005/10/12/svn-update-dry-run).

Comment: Above didn't work for me, had to run `svn merge --dry-run --revision BASE:HEAD .`

Comment: Getting "svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [16032:16061]; try updating first"

Comment: Great answer -- too bad it doesn't work on mixed revision working copies..  That'll learn me

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak - I love the irony q: `how do I ... without doing an update?` a: `first, do an update, then ...` :) :) :)

Comment: @Znarkus, the above will not work with Subversion version prior to 1.7.  In those you have to go to the direct directory where the changes are to issue the command (!).  That's because Subversion then used one .svn directory per directory.  Issuing it from the root of the working directory would only check for the files located there.  So in the end you still have to use `svn update -u`.

Answer (score 17):

This is what I was looking for.  Checked Google first, but `svn help` ended up coming through for me :)

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD .
```

Comment: Well, that will work with Subversion 1.7; the version that uses a single .svn at the root of the repo.  For older revisions of Subversion (unfortunately still in use) then  you have to issue the command in the directory where the change was submitted...  For those you must use `svn status -u` to get informed about what files have changed in the server.

Answer (score 16):

The same but shorter shorter :) :

```
svn st -u
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could make all your changes in a branch which you created for your own use. 
You would then be reasonably sure that you were the only one committing to it.

IMHO feature development should be done like this.

Then you could update this target machine from this branch instead of from the trunk.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'svn diff' to see the difference between your working copy and the repository.

Comment: Wrong. Those would only list the differences between you and the last time you synced with the repository. You will not see any differences that other people have committed to the repository in the meantime. The OP wants to know what those changes are, without applying them via an `svn update`

Comment: @Andrew meant to suggest that the OP run 'svn diff -r HEAD URL' to see the difference from the checked out files to what is checked in as the HEAD or top version in the repository.